# Google Data Studio Case When Two Sets of Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio, count-unique

I have a dataset in Google Sheets that records updates to projects over time:

```
Update_Date   Project_Code   Status
01/09/21      0001           Proposal
01/09/21      0002           Delivery
01/09/21      0003           Business Case
01/10/21      0001           Business Case
01/10/21      0002           Delivery
01/10/21      0003           Delivery
```

I am using this data as a Data Source in Google Data Studio. Is it possible to produce a count of the number of projects that have moved between `Status` values over time? For example, for the update on `01/10/21`, there is one project that has moved from `Proposal` to `Business Case` (`0001`).

I have tried to do this by creating a field and using `COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Update_Date = 01/09/21 and Status="Proposal" and Update_Date=01/10/21 and Status="Business Case" THEN Project_Code ELSE NULL END)` but I get an incorrect value of `0`, which I suspect is because I am referencing the same two variables twice in the one formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by converting each combination of values to a number in a separate field `x`:

```
CASE 
WHEN Update_Date=01/09/21 and Status="Proposal" THEN 1
WHEN Update_Date=01/10/21 and Status="Business Case" THEN 2
ELSE 0
END
```

then blending this data (using the automatic `SUM` aggregation) with a distinct count of the `Project_Code` field and finally filtering the result for those `Project_Code` values where `x` is equal to `3`